# Django how to define common url

Tags: django, url, tags

I am implementing a directory service and as you know listing URLs appear on a lot of places. I am aware of using the `{% url %}` tag, it's still not bullet proof for cases like global listing url structure changes, say I had `{% url id=listing.id %}` and had to add slug to the URL like `{% url id=listing.id slug=listing.slug %}`

While global search & replace is an option, however I am curious if there is a canonical way
to approach this issue.

Currently my approach is have a `listingurl.html` which only has `{% url id=listing.id slug=listing.slug %}` and wherever needs to have the url will just include `listingurl.html`, however I am not sure if implementing a custom filter would be more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure this works and if it is the most elegant solution:

some_template.html

```
{% include 'listing.html' with url_thing %}
```

listing.html

```
{% url url_thing id=object.id %}
```

Comment: this is my current method as well

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle it IMHO is to add a `get_absolute_url` method to your model. Then, instead of working about reversing the URL in the template, you can just call that method:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('listing_view_name', {'id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug})
```

Then:

```
<a href="{{ listing.get_absolute_url }}">{{ listing }}</a>
```

Comment: I heard about get_absolute_url, do I have to have this method name? Is this some kind of standard?

Comment: Yes, it's convention. The Django admin, in particular, will show a view on site link when editing an object if it has this method. I've also seen a number of third-party apps that make use of it if it exists.

Comment: hmmm just thought of one thing tho, what if I want to have the url to carry though query params?

Comment: You just have to manually add them after the URL in the href, i.e. `<a href="{{ listing.get_absolute_url }}?some_param=some_value">`

Comment: hmmm, then there is problem, say my site has a lot of listing links needs to carry the same kind query params, and if I need to change the params I ended up having the same original problem...

Comment: My example was simplified, but the query string doesn't have to be hardcoded, you can use variables like anywhere else in your template, i.e. `?some_param={{ foo }}`, or even items from the current request, i.e. `?some_param={{ request.GET.some_param }}`. The limitation here is due to how querystrings function. They are *data*, not part of the actual URL itself. In particular you can't create a urlpattern that contains a querystring, because that is not the URL Django will receive for the request.

Comment: Thanks but if but if put I put this <a href="{{ listing.get_absolute_url }}">{{ listing }}?category={{ request.GET.category }}</a> on everywhere and later on I found out I need to add one more query param, I end up having the original problem...